# AppCompat Toolbar Font Size Inconsistent in Portrait vs. Landscape

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I'm using this: https://xisberto.wordpress.com/2014/11/08/how-to-combine-actionbar-and-preferenceactivity-headers-with-appcompat/

[image]
[image]

The "Settings" font size changes between portrait and landscape. How do I keep it consistent?

Comment: I don't think it can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

It is normal, the toolbar height in portrait mode have 56 dp, in landscape 48 dp, the OS resize its height. Take care if you change the title size in landscape because you can put it higher than the toolbar.

Comment: It looks wrong and does not line up with the action icons/hamburger

Comment: @behelit thanks to that option, you can do this: http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/v_2/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7dHF1bjh0dnZpdlk/style_color_uiapplication_primary2.png

Answer (score 0):

Need to override toolbar title text size by adding

> app:titleTextAppearance

Toolbar XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Toolbar Style:

```
<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042331/android-toolbar-small-title-text-in-landscape-mode)