# Toolbar title textsize decreases on orientation change

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar, android-toolbar

The Toolbar title textsize gets decreased when I change orientation from portrait to landscape and gets reset when I change back to portrait. The activity in which this happens extends `ActionBarActivity` which uses `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: I think it's a known issue. Asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486858/appcompat-toolbar-font-size-inconsistent-in-portrait-vs-landscape

Comment: @Pooja My other activities don't face this issue.

Comment: That is working as intended. The landscape toolbar is shorter, so the text size is smaller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Toolbar: small title text in landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042331/android-toolbar-small-title-text-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 4):

Use the below solution:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Toolbar Style:

```
<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this problem exists in android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. Even I faced the same issue. But to maintain text size consistency I used the following method.

```
<style name="ToolbarText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
</style>
```

And use this style for toolbar.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 

    ....
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarText" />
```

Comment: You can resize from code is best, you can't  put 17sp,18sp.... 40sp.... in a future your code will deprecated ;)