# Support Action Bar not applying my style?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat, android-styles

I've been spending hours trying to fix the changing action bar title size according to this stack overflow post:
 [Android Toolbar: small title text in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042331/android-toolbar-small-title-text-in-landscape-mode)

Unfortunately, it seems that no matter what I do, anything regarding the actionbar style won't actually apply.

My styles v14 file:

```
<!-- Main theme -->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.MyTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.MyTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.MyTheme</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.MyTheme.DropDownItem</item>
</style>
```

My ActionBar styles:

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/my_title_style</item>
</style>

<style name="my_title_style" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

And, of course, "MyTheme" is applied in the manifest as well - I've even tried adding it to all the individual activities as well, to no avail.

It seems that no matter what I do, stuff just won't apply. I've tried removing the android: namespace, I've tried using titleTextAppearance instead of titleTextStyle, I've basically emulated exactly how the parent themes do it, but it won't change anything. Anybody have a clue as to what's going on? I just recently updated to AppCompat so I'm not totally familiar with how everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
<item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
<item name="titleTextStyle">@style/my_title_style</item>
```

for support library compatibility into your style.

Read [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html), section "`For Android 2.1 and higher`". Where it is given that you need to use two entries like

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>
```

---

So your complete style would be

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/my_title_style</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/my_title_style</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know if it's all that ou have made, but you have to add this code in the manifest(in the activity you want to apply this style):

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/appName"
    android:theme="@style/my_little_style" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

- Create a layout for your `Toolbar` and put a `TextView`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:background="#b2b2b2">

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
          android:textSize="20sp"
          android:textColor="#ff282828"/>

     </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  ```
- Include the `layout` in your `.xml`:

  ```
  <include layout="@layout/toolbar_activities"
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"/>
  ```
- Finally set a title in your `java class`:

  ```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);

  TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
  mTitle.setText("Your Title");
  setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
  ```