# Why title size not changed after rotation?

Tags: android

I have set `configChanges="orientation|landscape"` to keep Activity instance after rotation but now the title size in action bar not changes after rotation. I'm using AppCompat.
I'm trying to hide and show title again in onConfigurationChanged:

```
public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
}
```

And this not help.
How to set the title size changing after rotation?

I want to do something like this: 
[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

Images taken from this question: [Android Toolbar: small title text in landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042331/android-toolbar-small-title-text-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style of the title is in a configuration-specific XML file. If you don't recreate the view on configuration change, it will just stay as it is.

Solution: recreate the Activity on configuration change, or use a Fragment with setRetainInstance(true) which will be preserved while its view is re-created.