# Xamarin Forms title bar shrinks by 20% height

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app currently running on Android. The app's title bar keeps shrinking by about 20% or so whilst running. Probably when resuming an existing page after navigating to another.

Anybody else come across this?

Comment: Is the title bar coming from a `NavigationPage`? I have never personally seen, or at least noticed this.

Comment: Yes. I have since noticed that the title bar automatically "shrinks" in landscape view. It is too this size it is shrinking ... so presumably not handling a rotation or a return from another page or activity properly. I'm keeping an eye it, but thought this must be a common thing so I asked the open question!

Comment: Depends on what theme type you are using. With AppCompact, the default behavior is to keep the action bar the same size and shrink the Title (reference [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170707) issue where they say works as intended). It looks like you can change that behavior with a custom style ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28056935/3850012)). But it sounds like you are saying the actual bar itself is smaller. Are you sure? Maybe it just seems like it cause the text is smaller? Check what theme type you are using and if you're using a custom action bar or not.

Comment: I'm not using a custom action bar. I'm sure it's smaller along with its text and that rotating from landscape back to portrait "fixes" it

Comment: It might help to post the code for you custom action bar and maybe also the styles that could effect the action bar.